# How to update email address using 3 service providers - ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table 'EMPLOYEES' where the users have an incorrect email address.

[image]

I need to update the email address using 3 service providers like gmail, yahoo, outlook. I have a large number of records so I can't do it one by one.
How can I write that query to update them all at once.?

In the email column, each record must have a valid email address

The first record in my table in the email field is sking. After update it should become jusking@yahoo.com it should only take one domain not all 3 together.

The second record should be nkochhar@gmail.com
The third party ledhaan@yahoo.com
And so it should be with each record, one of the three domains must be added to make it a valid email address.

```
sking@gmail.com
nkochhar@yahoo.com
ldehaan@outlook.com
name4@yahoo.com
name5@outlook.com
name6@yahoo.com
name7@yahoo.com
name8@outlook.com
name@gmail.com
name@gmail.com
...
```

I found this on Google but I don't know how to apply it to what I need:

```
for (int i = 0; i <rowsCount; i ++) {
   cv.put (column2, columnValue [1]);
   cv.put (column3, columnValue [1]);
   db.update (tableName, cv, null, null);
}
```

I tried to do this but it shows an error:

[image]

I need help please, I'm a beginner at this :(

Comment: Please include sample data showing the input along with what the email should look like after the update.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand the problem properly. Do you want to update email field like sking@yahoo.com,sking@google.com,sking@outlook.com. Or please show the output you want

Comment: Yes. In the email column, each record must have a valid email address:
name@gmail.com
name@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update email field randomly with @outlook.com, @yahoo.com or @gmail.com use below query:

```
update employees
set email= (case when   mod(employee_id,3)=0 then concat(email,'@outlook.com') when mod(employee_id ,2)=1 then  concat(email,'@yahoo.com') else concat(email, '@gmail.com') end);
```

In both MySql and Oracle database this query will work fine.

Comment: The first record in my table in the email field is sking. after update it should become jusking@yahoo.com it should only take one domain not all 3.
The second record should be nkochhar@gmail.com
the third ledhaan@yahoo.com

Comment: sking@yahoo.com then nkochhar@gmail.com then again ledhaan@yahoo.com. When the @outlook.com will appear?

Comment: domains (gmail / outlokk / yahoo) may appear randomly when updated, it does not matter if they are in order but if they must be 3.

Comment: ok then you just want to have randomly created valid email address. It's not importand if they really exists or not.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter if the email accounts are real.
I just need to add one of these domain (@ gmail / @ outlokk / @ yahoo) to each record found in 'EMAIL'.
 This is just a task that my teacher asked me in a SQL course, but I can't make this statement.

Comment: shows an error when entering the request. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229213/discussion-between-kazi-mohammad-ali-nur-and-josefranc).